# Specified cast is not valid for different table?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Well here is the situation, from the table before I running this code is run perfectly. But when I change the table is getting error, while I think is not, because T_TEMPLATE_ID field is also an "int" just like the table before.

the error is: Specified cast is not valid

here's the code:

```
       DataTable dt;
       dt = getDownload(); // << here dt get table

       int iTemplateId = 3;
       IEnumerable<DataRow> query;

       try
       {
            query =
                from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where t.Field<double>("T_TEMPLATE_ID") == iTemplateId
                select t;

            // here comes the error
            dt = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
       }
       catch (Exception exp)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exp.Message, "Error");

       }
```

so what is the problem, am I getting wrong in other place?
I'm sorry if it's not clear enough, you can ask for more information :)

thanks before

Comment: can you post what is the real datatype of your T_TEMPLATE_ID column on your database table?

Comment: hmm, where can I can see that? :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mr.Rendezvous could you try this:

Check if test will have a result. Add breakpoint on test and on boundTable.

```
            IEnumerable<DataRow> test =
            from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where Convert.ToInt32(t["T_TEMPLATE_ID"]) == iTemplateId
            select t;

            if(test.count() > 0)
            {
            //recods Found!
            DataTable boundTable  = test.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
            }
            else
            {
              //no Recods found!
            }
```

DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(Of T) Method (IEnumerable(Of T)) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

Regards

Comment: :) I also used that on my winforms apps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your field type is not actually a `double` but an `int`.  Your query tries to (implicitly) unbox an `int` as a `double` causing the cast error.  Change the query so the field is read as an `int`.

```
from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
where t.Field<int>("T_TEMPLATE_ID") == iTemplateId
select t;
```

Comment: Well it seems that your field wasn't actually declared an `int` but was probably a `string`...

Comment: hmm I dunno, but the column I prepare is typeof(int)